# Identity Server Add Claim Based Upon the Guid Generated in ResourceOwnerPassword Validator

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ide, asp.net-identity

I'm implement the Identity Server 4 Using the ASP.Net Core.I want to add the Claim Based Upon the Guid Generated in the Class ResourceOwnerPasswordValidator which is Inherited from IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator.(Claims are Generated in ProfileService Class which is Inherited from IProfileService).How to Pass arguments  between these two Classes.

```
     public Task ValidateAsync(ResourceOwnerPasswordValidationContext context)
    {
        int res = verifyUser.verify(context.UserName, context.Password, context.Request.Client.ClientId);
        if (res == 1)
        {
            context.Result.Error = "Invalid User";
            context.Result.ErrorDescription = "Email ID doesnot Resgistered";
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
        else if (res == 2)
        {
            context.Result.Error = "Verify Mail";
            context.Result.ErrorDescription = "Please Verify Your Mail";
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
        else if (res == 4)
        {
            context.Result.Error = "Invalid Password";
            context.Result.ErrorDescription = "Password Missmatch";
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
        else
        {
            Guid claim=verifyUser.GetGuid(context.UserName);
             //For this Guid Claim Should be added in ProfileService
            context.Result = new GrantValidationResult("", authenticationMethod: context.UserName);
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
```

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Context is the Common argument between these two Classes.By update the Context(Any one value based upon our convenience) in ResourceOwnerPasswordValidator Class we can use that Guid in another class(ProfileService).